# Использование переменной после закрытия диалога в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы после ввода текста в диалоге, эта информация сохранялась там и после закрытия диалога. Переменные - `text`, `countMess`.

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
    QInputDialog, QApplication)
import sys, os, pyautogui, time, random

global text
global countMess

text = "Текст не установлен"

class MainBtn():
    def maindo(self, countMess):
        time.sleep(5)
        countMess -= 1
        countNow = 0
        while countNow <= countMess:
            protect_first = str(random.randint(0, 1000000000))
            protect_second = str(random.randint(0, 1000000000))
            pyautogui.press("t")
            pyautogui.typewrite("[" +protect_first+ "] " +str(text)+ " [" +protect_second+ "]")
            pyautogui.press("enter")
            countNow += 1
            if countNow == 3:
                time.sleep(5)

    def start(self):
        os.system("msg %username% У вас пять секунд для возврата в игру!")
        MainBtn.maindo(self, countMess)

def changetext():
#   text = QInputDialog.getText('Установка текста', 'Установить текст на ')
    text = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Текст', 'Введите текст: ')
    print("text = " +str(text)) 

def changecount():
#   text = QInputDialog.getText('Установка текста', 'Установить текст на ')
    countMess = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Количество', 'Введите количество: ') # <-----
    print("countMess = " +str(countMess))

def switchlobby():
    print("countMess = " +str(countMess))
    print("text = " +str(text))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = uic.loadUi("insanemacro.ui")

    window.move(0, 0)
    window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    window.setWindowTitle("InsaneMacro")
    ico = QtGui.QIcon("icon.png")
    app.setWindowIcon(ico)

    #window.btnChangeText.clicked.connect(changetext)
    window.btnStart.clicked.connect(MainBtn.start)
    window.btnSetText.clicked.connect(changetext)
    window.btnSetCount.clicked.connect(changecount)
    window.btnSwitchLobby.clicked.connect(switchlobby)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: вы забыли опубликовать `insanemacro.ui`

Comment: У вас какая-то фигня с отступами, поправьте, чтобы код стал валидным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что установка значения в переменные не происходит глобально -- вместо этого создаются новые локальные объекты.

Для использования глобальных переменных объявите их правильно, вместо:

```
...
global text
global countMess

text = "Текст не установлен"
...
```

оставьте инициализацию их:

```
...
text = "Текст не установлен"
countMess = 0
...
```

А в тех функциях, где вы хотели уставить им значения вызовите `global <название_переменной>`:

```
def changetext():
    global text
    text = ...
    ...

...
def changecount():
    global countMess
    countMess = ...
```

---

**PS.**

Советую через создание своего класса сделать это, т.к. глобальные переменные могут запутать код. Например, в том классе ваши переменные `text` и `countMess` стали бы полями класса и были бы доступны во всех его методах

Comment: @Slavatar  Почему глобальные переменные являются злом? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil